# Incorrect user association to a question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I find that this Superuser question,
[**Concatenate pdfs without losing bookmarks**](https://superuser.com/questions/23033/concatenate-pdfs-without-losing-bookmarks)

- shows last-modified by "`John T`" when the question is listed
  (for example [recently active `pdf` tagged questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=pdf&sort=active&pagesize=30)),
- while, the question page itself says last-modified by "`EvilChookie`".

The [revision page for the question](https://superuser.com/revisions/23033/list) does not show "`John T`" anywhere.

Is this a bug?
I don't understand how my cache could do something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Could someone have posted an answer and then deleted it? That would change the listing on the question listing, but not show up in the view over the question.

Comment: Don't forget the caching of pages.

Comment: @random, what is your experience for the example in question?

Comment: @random, What happens if you open a new browser, enter the Beta password and then open the links from my question one by one? (I get a reproduction)

Comment: this is correct, answer was posted and then deleted.